# How to read distance of passing object?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, lcd

Ok, guys this is my first post and I am new to Arduino but somewhat familiar with programming so I hope you guys can assist me. If any of this is confusing, I apologize in advance! :)

I want to be able to utilize a TOF sensor that will be stationary to capture the distance of a passing object at a certain moment after it is first detected, because it is round. So I wanted to use a photoelectric switch, so when the object would pass, it would send the signal to the TOF sensor to read the distance 17ms after that moment.(I've done the math, and the delay to be in the center(closest edge to the sensor of solid ball) of the object passing would take 17ms) Then I would like to have that distance be displayed onto a LCD screen, until the next object passes and the process repeats....Think of a conveyor belt with a basketball on it. The basketball would be moving and pass the sensor, but the distance to the center(closest edge to the sensor)of the ball would be measured at a certain moment and displayed until the next ball passes.

The next problem is that the distance needs to be converted to a "zone" So like between 10-12cm, it would = 2. 12.1-14 would be 3 etc... The last part is probably the easiest but, I have no idea where to start...I appreciate all who helps!

I was needing help with the code to make this work with the Arduino uno. The tof sensor is VL53L1X and E-931-S35RRQ photoelectric sensor. And the LCD will be a 7 segment display so as long as it’s programmed for that I can change out sizes later..

Comment: @velocitygraphix - I've removed the "financial reward" part of your question because the Stack Exchange community frowns on monetary bounties for questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316137/what-to-do-when-op-offers-payment-for-solution

Comment: Yes all the balls are the same size. I’m not trying to find the size of the ball, only the distance to each one as it passes and then display it. Thanks!

Comment: Distance to the middle of the ball?...I’m not sure how you would word to say the middle of the ball..(halfway on the surface of the circumference?)...it’s a solid ball so the time of flight sensor would need to measure the closest edge of the ball-on the surface...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by closest approach but I want it measured to the part of the ball that is closest to the sensor which will fall halfway from front to back when passing. Picture if you pointed your finger out horizontally at a height exactly half the diameter of the ball...your finger is the sensor. Now if a ball rolls by and grazes your finger, that is the closest edge to the finger (sensor) that should be measured...

Comment: The ball part may be confusing you, as the shape doesn’t matter as long as the sensor takes a distance reading 17ms after the beam is broken...as long as the sensor takes a reading at that exact time, it’ll automatically be measuring to the correct part of the object.

Comment: i understand now ... you do not have it in your mind clearly ... as a result, your post is just a mess of irrelevant information ... all you want is for the TOF sensor to take a distance reading 17ms after a trigger signal ... you only need one sentence to ask that, not several paragraphs

Comment: Well sort of. I wanted to explain in detail. It also needs to hold the reading on a display until the next object passes...as well as convert the distance to “zones”...

Comment: Is there any specific question about this project? And do you already have the TOF sensor? Or at least have chosen one?

Answer (score 0):

So break this into parts and solve each part separately. First, figure out how to interface the photoelectric sensor. First just write a loop() that waits for the state change when the sensor trips.

To get accurate timing you'll probably want to respond to the photoelectric sensor with an interrupt service routine that starts a timer. Get that working next.

Then figure out how to interface with your ToF sensor. When I googled it I found the bare sensor as well as versions on PC boards with an I2C interface. You may be able to find somebody's library that interfaces with the sensor. Get that working so you can take readings from the TOF sensor.

Then figure out how to drive the 7-segment display. Just write code that displays the values from 0-9 for 1 second each using a delay.

Once you've got all the pieces working separately, it's time to map out the logic if your program and make it work. Take a look at the "arduino blink without delay" example for how to write code that handles timed responses without using the `delay()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The sensor has a 50Hz ranging frequency; depending on the speed of the balls passing the measuring section, you may only need to wait for ranges of less than (whatever passes for inifinity in your setup) and then track the ranges until they hit a minimum, save that value, and there's your first answer. This saves a detector and has the additional virtue of being independent of the speed of the traveling ball (up to a resolution limited by the sensor's measuring frequency & your precision requirements).

The second part just needs a few `ifs`, such as:

```
if( range < 10.0 ){
  zone = 1;   // or whatever else you need to do here
}
else if( range < 12.0 ){
  zone = 2;
}
else {
  zone = 3;   // anywhere else
}
```